# ReportViewer not working on web server

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, reportviewer, .net-framework-version

Over the last month, I developed a WebForm app in C# with VS2013. It is working perfectly when I debug it and almost perfectly too once published on my iis 7.5 server on a App Pool using .NET Framework v4.030319. The problem is that the report viewer control doesn't work, exactly like this blog:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webtopics/archive/2009/02/10/report-viewer-toolbar-does-not-render-properly-on-iis-7-0.aspx

or the 49 other blogs I have read in the last 4 days... I tried every solution suggested and none of them worked. I am 100% sure it's not due to my report because just for testing, I created a basic report (just a textbox, no parameters, no datasource) and a new project with one page that load this report and I got the same problem.

Here is the concerned code in the web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
  <authentication mode="None" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    </assemblies>
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
    </buildProviders>
  </compilation>
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  [...]
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
  </modules>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <handlers>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControl" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And yes, I the mapping is also created on the server. Can someone help me fix this problem. I'm a little distraught.

Comment: Is the IIS pool set that your app is under configured for 'Integrated' Mode?

Comment: Yes it is set to Integrated and the identity is an admin user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally resolved it by installing the followings on the server:

- dotNetFx45
- ReportViewer 2010 Redistributable
- Microsoft Microsoft System CLR Types for SQL Server 2012
- ReportViewer 2012 Runtime

and restart it after even if it's not asked. After that, the reports were displaying properly. The fact that I didn't get any error messages wasn't helping very much. Also, the server is on prod so I couldn't restart it every time I want. Anyway, it's working now and that's the only thing that matters. Thanks.

Comment: Reinstalling CLR types and fixing a custom javascript error resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me these 2 mentioned below and no server restart worked
ReportViewer 2010 Redistributable
ReportViewer 2012 Runtime
Thanks